# how to disable Extensions Toolbar Menu from chrome (with latest version)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I had disabled Extensions Toolbar Menu with following command line option:

--disable-features=ExtensionsToolbarMenu

With new updates, this option stopped to work.  "Extensions Toolbar Menu" hides the active extensions. I need to see all my active extensions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Chrome & type chrome://flags/ in the `URL` and hit enter
2. Search for `Extensions Toolbar`
3. Open the dropdown and select `Disabled`
4. Restart Chrome

Comment: flag "Extensions Toolbar" is not present in chrome://flags/

Comment: the flag is gone, https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/153789-how-enable-disable-extensions-toolbar-menu-google-chrome.html